# How can I make the application of curses a profitable industry?

Tags: balancing-magic-systems

In the 1800s, a woman named Marie Leaveau operated an underground black market that centered around the occult. Known as the Voodoo queen of Louisiana, she plied her trade performing curses to selected targets, offering her services around the country to those who could afford them. This gave the buyer anonymity and left no trace that a crime was committed.

Voodoo is a specialized form of magic that works by way of controlling the actions or fate of a specific target. This is enacted through a ritual that requires multiple ingredients. The most essential of these would be something personal belongings to the target, such as an item or body part, to apply curses to them by proxy.

Through the ritual, the user created a bind between them and the target's soul, allowing them to transmit the curse. However, this doesn't come without consequence. Whatever so done to the target by the curse, the user will receive damage equivalent to that effect. If the curse causes a target to become paralyzed from the waist down, the user will receive some equal disability related to that effect (losing eyesight). If the victim dies through some disease, the user will drop dead at the end of the curse, and so on. This is why people don't go around cursing each other, as both parties would suffer in equal measure.

This obviously is not suitable as a long term business strategy for an entrepreneurial-minded witch. There's no sense in performing paid services for clients if it commits damage to herself. How can she break the system and get around this rule to make her trade profitable?

Comment: Clarification : what happens if client A who is a bald curses subject B hairs to ignite in daylight? Because maybe client A kept a thread of hair and the curse follows through... How bout amputee, tattoo, nose ring, pacifier, you get the drift. ;D

Comment: How is blindness related to being paralyzed?

Comment: @user6760 Or if you curse someone with something that is *bad* when it happens to them, but *good* when it happens to you.  A half-deaf individual who curses their enemies to have their hearing become massively more sensitive.  The dwarf who curses their giant bully to double in height.  The obese person who curses their enemy to loose half their body-weight.  The spurned lover who curses his cheating ex-wife to be constantly propositioned by horny beautiful nymphomaniac women.

Comment: Is it common knowledge that curses are two way affairs? If not, a travelling witch in the 1800's could simply not tell the clients about the side effects and move on to the next town before they are noticed. Similar to the classic deal-with-the-devil situation, which never goes quite as expected.

Comment: @DBS The person invoking the curse (the witch) is the one who suffers the ill effects along with the target, not the person who pays her to do it. From the question, "There's no sense in performing paid services for clients if it commits damage to herself."

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If your witch can create these bonds without actively being the user then this seems like an excellent way to profiteer off those seeking revenge.

Someone already paralysed you in a car crash? The witch will bind you to them so you can take their legs away. Can't make your situation any worse.

Insurance company denied your claim for end-of-life care due to terminal illness?  Use what little money you have left to buy a curse-binding and give the CEO cancer.

Ex on your mind? The Witch will hook you up with a soul bind, some painkillers and a knife. Get to mutilating so they'll never cheat on anyone ever again.

Murderer of your wife and child just walked free from court? Go to the witch, bind your soul to theirs and then take a dive off the nearest tower block.

Basically: This <s>sociopath</s> entrepreneur's target market is those who are already damaged, desperate or suicidal. Exploiting the darkest emotions in those people will allow her to drive them to both pay her and take the damage themselves.

And if they later regret the consequences of their actions? Sucks to be them. They signed a waiver.

Comment: Good answer. Hits from several directions at once.

Comment: "Murderer of you wife and child just walked free from court" Of course, the only drawback is that you're royally screwed if he has already been immolated by the neighbors...

Comment: For the sufficiently rich, damaged customers can be used as proxies. Have cancer, want to die anway? Why not ensure your family will be taken care of while you're at it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: See L.Dutch’s answer. :-)

Comment: *And if they later regret the consequences of their actions?* They go to your competitor and get you cursed.

Answer (score 14):

> There's no sense in performing paid services for clients if it commits damage to herself.

You probably never heard of weapon industry if you think so.

The entrepreneur creates the bond between the customer and the target (via an IP protected procedure), but then it's up to the customer/user to chant the curse and take the damage.

Of course this limits the customer pool to those who can afford a "scapegoat" who will take the damage in their place: 3 letters agencies, organized crime, well off people.

Answer (score 14):

### It doesn't work only for pain, but also pleasure

This answer may reframe too much of your question, but the basic idea is that while it can be used to harm the bound person, it could also work to bring them pleasure.

The target enjoyed a good meal? Well, now you feel good too.

You just double the amount of happiness between the two bound people. And imagine how great of an experience it would be to have sex with the bound person.

Answer (score 9):

One could wonder how such equal-measures cursing was developed in the first place. Perhaps it was developed by otherwise powerless people to strike back at oppressors. A mother could e.g. inflict pain on the nobleman who raped her daugther, even it means pain to herself, or a slave would be willing to give his live to kill the one who has enslaved his tribe.

If the damage done to the curser can be redirected to a proxy, who is willing or forced to utter the final words of the ritual or otherwise receive the bad end of the stick, the problem is reduced. The witch (or whatever) can make a deal with authorities to punish criminals this way, or she could buy slaves to inflict the reflected curse on. Or maybe she could pay old or crippled people handsomely, enabling them or their children a better life at the cost of being cursed.

To be truly balancing, however, the witch should not be able to redirect the curse. Then if becomes a matter of setting the price high enough. You want the Queen to become barren? Okay, I can live with not having any more children, but it will cost you. Same with losing an eye, becoming lame in one leg, etc. I will accept warts if the price is right. A death curse? Maybe when I am old and feeble and the money will go to my children or a good cause.

Rich and powerful customers may be able to give the witch a very comfortable life by buying a single curse every few years. If the curses have time limits, she can sell them again once they wear off - or plan to retire in good health once they all wear off.

Comment: So *that's* why witches are all warty old crones! I always wondered why they look like that.

Answer (score 7):

Don't *just* sell curses - sell "protection plans" too.

For a monthly subscription fee, which is *significantly* less than the price of a curse, the witch will add you to a "Do Not Curse" list, and will refuse contracts to curse you.

If you want to splurge on a premium package, the witch will *also* tell you when someone tries to get you cursed - and who it was.

If the witch is smart, she doesn't admit that this is a "Do Not Curse" list, she just lists it as a "protection from curses" which must be renewed, and imply that this is some form of magical protection/ward.  This would also allow her to charge the would-be cursers, then later reveal that the curse did not take effect because the target was protected, and offer a *partial* refund as a "gesture of good will".

Comment: “Gee. Mighty cursable looking face you’ve got there. You might want to think about buying some... protection...”

Answer (score 5):

## Cross Cursing

So instead of having the client be on the receiving end of the curse, instead put a different client's target who is seeking similar level of infliction on the other end of the curse.

In secret prep and do as much of the ritual as possible, and then find one of the targets and as discreetly as possible do the binding necessary to enact the curse.  At this point the the original target will get their curse while the recoil from the curse gets dealt to a different target.

## Recruit Minions for Clients

An alternative is to recruit unsuspecting people to serve as proxies for the clients. They have no idea what they are getting themselves into, and once it is done, Madam Marie Leaveau is no where to be found.

Comment: [Reminds me of a film...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangers_on_a_Train_(film))

Answer (score 3):

Find a masochist who's into S&M, and is happy to let you bind them to the victim and then (consensually) do all kinds of things to them that will be painful for the target. You won't do any lasting damage this way, but it's certainly a way to inflect pain on people.

Depending on how your magic works, you might also be able to drug your your volunteer (with painkillers, for example), and then perform actions on them that they don't feel but the victim would. Being bound to a someone who was undergoing surgery would be a very unpleasant experience if you didn't get the effects of the anaesthetic.

This could also be used to cause more lasting harm - find someone who's about to undergo a legitimate medical amputation and pay them to let you bind them to the victim.

Answer (score 2):

### Exploit the Desperate

This is going to assume that you can have another person perform the curse or take on the backlash of it willingly. The Voodoo Queen obviously isn't going to be able to do enough curses to become famous if she ends up crippled and blind after the first handful, so I think it is a fair assumption.

As long as you are able to get another person to take on the cost of casting the curse, find those people shouldn't be too difficult. Search through the local poor population, especially the homeless or those just barely scraping by. Find someone in really dire straits and then offer to take care of them for as long as they suffer the curse backlash. If you ask enough desperate people "Would you be willing to go blind if it meant having a house and someone to take care of you" eventually one of them will say yes.

The Voodoo Queen would have to start small to build up a rep, but once word gets out that she really does keep her word and take care of the people who cast her spells she should have a ready supply of volunteers. The more serious the curse the better the compensation would have to be. I would imagine that for small things like common illnesses or afflictions the volunteer would just get a lump sum of money. Something like being blinded or crippled would require a promise to take care of the volunteer for as long as it lasted. Death curses would have to require taking care of the volunteer's family or designated survivors for the rest of their lives, since obviously the backlash for death is still death.

Now, is exploiting the impoverished and desperate ethical or going to leave you happy when you look in a mirror? Of course not. But if that bothered you chances are you wouldn't have gotten into the curses for money game to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds kinda like practical Karma, essentially a kind of force, a moral force, but physical, like gravity. Curses are Karma transfers. Witches are Karma engineers, and there would be rules about how to do it safely. You could attack the problem from an ethics standpoint, but this sounds more like an electrical engineering challenge: how to move the Karmic charge from A to B.

Witches would be harmed occasionally, just like electricians get shocked, but it would be by accident or mistake. It would not be surprising that early practitioners would be harmed; look what happened to Marie Curie.

There would be wide-ranging effects and many practical applications: justice systems, personal protection, armed conflict. Ethical engineers would get a lot of work, most of it deeply unethical.

Imagine an ethical ground-wire! Babies?

Answer (score 0):

**Mental pain**

The victim ruined your life and made you homeless? You now live in a cardboard box? Curse their home on fire. You can easily get another cardboard box. Some witches have special rates for the needy or will allow you deferred payments. Of course you'd better pay ...